# Linq Multiple Joins

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have some sql tables that I need to query information from my current query that returns a single column list is:

```
from f in FactSales
where f.DateKey == 20130921
where f.CompanyID <= 1
join item in DimMenuItems
on f.MenuItemKey equals item.MenuItemKey
join dmi in DimMenuItemDepts
on item.MenuItemDeptKey equals dmi.MenuItemDeptKey
group f by dmi.MenuItemDeptKey into c
select new {
Amount = c.Sum(l=>l.Amount)
}
```

This returns the data I want and it groups correctly by the third table I join but I cannot get the Description column from the dmi table. I have tried to add the field

```
 Description = dmi.Description
```

but it doesnt work. How can I get data from the third table into the new select that I am creating with this statement? Many thanks for any help.

Comment: you need to group by description as well, in order to add it to your select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you are using Entity Framework COMPLETELY WRONG. Linq is NOT SQL.

You shouldn't be using `join`. Instead you should be using Associations.

So instead, your query should look like...

```
from sale in FactSales
where sale.DateKey == 20130921
where sale.CompanyID <= 1
group sale by sale.Item.Department into c
select new 
{
    Amount = c.Sum(l => l.Amount)
    Department = c.Key
}
```

By following Associations, you will automatically be implicitly joining.

You should not be grouping by the id of the "table" but by the actual "row", or in Object parlance (which is what you should be using in EF, since the raison d'etre of an ORM is to convert DB to Object), is that you should be grouping by the "entity" rather than they the "entity's key".

EF already knows that the key is unique to the entity.

The grouping key word only allows you to access `sale` and `sale.Item.Department` after it. It is a transform, rather than an operator like in SQL.

Comment: There is no option to directly link the menuitemkey to the department table at least according to Intellisense. Is it possible that these associations have not been created? I created the entities based on a preexisting db rather than using the designer when creating my data models.

Comment: It is more than likely that the association's we not created. The associations are normally autogenerated by the DbFirst edmx wizard based on foreign keys. If they are missing its because your DB doesn't use foreign keys, which is generally a really bad thing.

Comment: I have no control over how the database is created its being modeled off of a data warehouse that feeds an olap cube. Can the associations be created manually? I only have a few that are of great importance otherwise i dont need them very much

Comment: @NateGreen You can add the associations into the edmx yourself. It's a little complicated, but worth it.

Comment: Well thanks for the help looks like I have some researching to do.